# How to scrape website if it has load more button to load more content on the page?

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\gkhat\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/233/world-cuisine/asian/indian/')
card_titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card__detailsContainer')
button = driver.find_element_by_id('category-page-list-related-load-more-button')
for card_title in card_titles:
    rname = card_title.find_element_by_class_name('card__title').text
    print(rname)

    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

The [website](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/233/world-cuisine/asian/indian/) loads the food cards after clicking on the the "Load More" button the above code scrape the recipe title I want it keep scraping the title even after clicking the load more button.
I tried the going to the Network tab the clicking on XHR but none of the requests shows the JSON. What should I do?

Comment: If you use selenium which is the second slowest way to scrape stuff (after doing it manually) then you can just find the ID of the button.

Another solution would be to check the json responses in the network tab of your browser when you click the button. Look for the parameters in the request: Probably there is a `page` variable you can change - If there is a such variable you can just make a simple HTTP request to get the json and increment the page number in a for loop.

Comment: @mama - the page variable shows a blank response. - I did find the id of the button but I'm not sure how to move further what to do or how to loop so that it can continue scraping after clicking the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below code for that. It works, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. FYI I handled those pop-ups for `email` manually. You need to find a way to handle them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/233/world-cuisine/asian/indian/")
receipes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("card__detailsContainer")
for rec in receipes:
    name = rec.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").get_attribute("innerText")
    print(name)
loadmore = driver.find_element_by_id("category-page-list-related-load-more-button")
j = 0
try:
    while loadmore.is_displayed():
        loadmore.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        lrec = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("recipeCard__detailsContainer")
        newlist = lrec[j:]
        for rec in newlist:
            name = rec.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").get_attribute("innerText")
            print(name)
        j = len(lrec)+1
        time.sleep(5)
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    pass
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a json that returns the data. However the json returns it in html, so just need to parse that.

Note: You can change the chunk size so you can get more than 24 items per "page"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

size = 24
page = 0

hasNext = True
while hasNext == True:
    page +=1
    print('\tPage: %s' %page)
    url = 'https://www.allrecipes.com/element-api/content-proxy/aggregate-load-more?sourceFilter%5B%5D=alrcom&id=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_2007692&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fallrecipes_recipe_alrcom_142967&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_231026&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_247233&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_246179&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_256599&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_247204&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_34591&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_245131&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_220560&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_212721&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_236563&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fallrecipes_recipe_alrcom_14565&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_8189766&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_8188886&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_8189135&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_2052087&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_7986932&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_2040338&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_280310&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_142967&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_14565&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_228957&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_46822&excludeIds%5B%5D=cms%2Fonecms_posts_alrcom_72349&page={page}&orderBy=Popularity30Days&docTypeFilter%5B%5D=content-type-recipe&docTypeFilter%5B%5D=content-type-gallery&size={size}&pagesize={size}&x-ssst=iTv629LHnNxfbQ1iVslBTZJTH69zVWEa&variant=food'.format(size=size, page=page)
    jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
    
    hasNext = jsonData['hasNext']

    soup = BeautifulSoup(jsonData['html'], 'html.parser')
    cardTitles = soup.find_all('h3',{'class':'recipeCard__title'})
    for title in cardTitles:
        print(title.text.strip())
```

Answer (score -1):

For this purpose, you can also use the command

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath()
```

For that, right-click on the loadmore button. After that **In Chrome** you choose [Inspect-> copy-> copy full xPath], while in **in Firefox** it be [Inspect-> copy-> XPath]. Now you do the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("here you put the code you copied for the button").click()
```

***Example of a copied code***

> /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]